# Is it correct that designing a n-tier architecture application where each layer is a plug-in component?

Tags: plugins, n-tier-architecture

I want to create an application with n-tier architecture. I want to design each layer as a plug-in component.

Is it correct that designing a n-tier architecture application where each layer is a plug-in component?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how I'd think of an n-Tier application- it sounds more like a pluggable architecture to me.

Usually n-Tier architectures define a tier as a physical layer- so your client is one one physical machine, business logic is on a second and the datastore is on a third.

If you design appropriately, you can plugin components on each of those tiers, but the existence of plugins by themselves does not make an n-Tier appllication.